# XenServer export fails

Tags: xenserver, export

When I try to export a virtual machine using XenCenter, it fails weirdly; XenCenter creates a "Transfer VM" that should do the export, but that VM failts to start and gets stuck in "stopped" status.

I already had a look at the Transfer VM template and removed an older version.

Right now I'm trying with XenServer 7.3, but it didn't work in previous versions either.

Also, in XenCenter there is no useful logging, I just see "failed to export" notifications and that's it.

Comment: @Damon I updated the question. My Problem is that I cannot make a copy of the VM in the first place.

Comment: Can you work around the issue?  I export (for backup purposes) via the menu in XenCenter "VM > Export" and it works great but no "Transfer VM" is used; It's just a dialog you work through.  I am assuming you need more functionality/automation than the menu provides or something?  Citrix doesn't really document the "Transfer VM" very well it seems.

Comment: @Damon that is exactly what I'm doing. This does in fact use a Transfer VM, but it is hidden by default. You can see it when you select View->Hidden Objects from the menu.

Comment: I have been exporting as a XVA file in our relatively simple infrastructure. I just exported again to XVA file and it worked BUT exporting to an OVF/OVA package did NOT work and gave the same result you are experiencing.  I still cannot find the transfer VM they mention even with hidden objects shown, but this probably is my own ignorance.   You might seek support from Citrix's forums.    There are a couple very knowledgeable rovers over there; not that someone here might help but it seems to be a slow go for you here.  I'm no help!

Comment: That was acually a good hint! Tried to export to an XVA:  it doesn't need/create a Transfer VM and it actually exports well. So now I just need to find a tool to convert from xva to ovf.